# About asynchronous tasks

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a form with a button and a list box. I want to add to the list box the results from two functions. These two functions can take an unknown amount of time to complete and I want to execute them simultaneously. As soon as either of the functions completes the computation, I want to display the result in the list box (before the other function completed). At the moment, the results are displayed after both functions complete. I wouldn't mind if the functions update the list box themselves.

```
    async Task<string> LongTaskAsync()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        return "Completed long task async";
    }

    async Task<string> ShortTaskAsync()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        return "Completed short task async";
    }

    async void BtnRunClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        var longTask = Task.Run(() => LongTaskAsync());
        var shortTask = Task.Run(() => ShortTaskAsync());

        listBox1.Items.Add(await longTask);
        listBox1.Items.Add(await shortTask);        
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep` with tasks. Use `Task.Delay` and `await` that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll do that in the future. For this example, I don't think it matters.

Comment: Yea I know it doesn't solve anything regarding the question but I'm just saying :)

Comment: I don't have time to answer right now but take a look at `ContinueWith`, I think you can solve it with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it shows 2 of them at the same time related how you chain your awaits.

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(await longTask);
 listBox1.Items.Add(await shortTask);
```

You are awaiting longer task before the shorter one. The second line runs after long task done its work in this time shorter one was already completed that's why you see them at the same time. But in a world you don't know what task will take longer to execute you need to have a better solution.

```
  Action<Task<string>> continuationFunction = t => { this.listBox1.Items.Add(t.Result); };
  Task.Run(() => LongTaskAsync()).ContinueWith(continuationFunction, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 
  Task.Run(() => ShortTaskAsync()).ContinueWith(continuationFunction, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` is for to avoid cross thread access exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `ContinueWith` for this. It's almost always possible to avoid mixing `async/await` and `ContinueWith`-style of continuations. In your case, it can be done like this:

```
async void BtnRunClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    async Task longTaskHelperAsync() {
        // probably, Task.Run is redundant here,
        // could just do: var item = await LongTaskAsync();
        var item = await Task.Run(() => LongTaskAsync()); 
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }

    async Task shortTaskHelperAsync() {
        // probably, Task.Run is redundant here, too
        var item = await Task.Run(() => ShortTaskAsync()); 
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(longTaskHelperAsync(), shortTaskHelperAsync());
}
```

I believe this way it's more readable and you don't have to worry about synchronization context, `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`, etc.

Also, most likely you'd want to take care of possible re-entrancy, if `BtnRunClick`is clicked again while those async ctasks are still in-flight.

Comment: Thanks Noseratio. It works and it looks more digestible than the other code. I think you placed the two async functions by mistake inside the BtnRunClick function.

Comment: @Nick_F, are you targeting C# 7.0+, which has support for [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)?

Comment: @Nick_F, then you can still use async lambdas for local functions: `Func<Task> longTaskHelperAsync = async ()  => { ... };`

Comment: Yes, I moved the two local functions outside and it runs fine.

Comment: @Nick_F, yes it's a good idea to move them out if you can. The only reason I used local functions was to show that you can do pretty much everything you could with `ContinueWith` lambdas, including having access to local variables.

Comment: It's excellent that I can update the listbox from asynchronous functions. Now I have a lot of work fixing bad programming in my programs :)

Comment: @Nick_F, you may still want to look at using the MVVM pattern to update the UI, including listboxes. Here's a [great article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding) by Stephen Cleary on how to combine async operations with MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it a bit more generically by creating a method that awaits a task, and also adds the result of the task to the `ListBox`.

```
async Task ProcessAndAddToListAsync(Func<Task<string>> function)
{
    var value = await Task.Run(function); // Start the task in a background thread
    listBox1.Items.Add(value); // Update the control in the UI thread
}
```

Then use this method inside the event handler of the button-click event:

```
async void BtnRunClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    var longTask = ProcessAndAddToListAsync(LongTaskAsync);
    var shortTask = ProcessAndAddToListAsync(ShortTaskAsync);

    await Task.WhenAll(longTask, shortTask); // optional
    // Here do anything that depends on both tasks being completed
}
```

Comment: Thank you Theodor, this solution is even better - only one additional function was needed.

Comment: It appears I can change the return type of the functions LongTaskAsync() and ShortTaskAsync() to string and I still got the desired outcome. They should be renamed LongTask() and ShortTask(). The original functions, the way I created them lack the await operator anyway.

Comment: @Nick_F yeap, [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) is a versatile method, and can handle sync and async delegates equally well.

Comment: Theodor, if my functions have arguments, how do I call them from Task.Run?

Comment: @Nick_F You could use lambdas to pass ad hoc arguments: `ProcessAndAddToListAsync(() => LongTaskAsync(arg1, arg2))`